# Scrapy, how to limit time per domain?

Tags: python, time, scrapy

I have been searching for an answer and there is no answer on this forum although several questions have been asked. One answer is the it is possible to stop spider after certain time but that is not suitable for me because I usually launch 10 websites per spider. So my challenge is that I have spider for 10 websited and I would like to limit time to 20 seconds per domain in order to avoid getting stuck at some webshop. How to do it?

In general I can also tell you that I crawl 2000 company websites and in order to make it in one day I divide these websites into 200 groups of 10 websites and I launch 200 spiders in parallel. That may be amateur but that I the best that I know. The computer almost freezes because spiders consume entire CPU and memory, but next day I have the results. What I am looking for is employment webpages on companies' websites. Does anyone have any better idea how to crawl 2000 websites ? In case there is a webshop among websites the crawling could take days, so that is why I would like to limit the time per domain.

Thank you in advance.

Marko

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# encoding=UTF-8  
import scrapy, urlparse, time, sys
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from urlparse import urlparse, urljoin
from vacancies.items import JobItem

#We need that in order to force Slovenian pages instead of English pages. It happened at "http://www.g-gmi.si/gmiweb/" that only English pages were found and no Slovenian.
from scrapy.conf import settings
settings.overrides['DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS'] = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Language':'sl',}
#Settings.set(name, value, priority='cmdline')
#settings.overrides['DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS'] = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Language':'sl','en':q=0.8,}




#start_time = time.time()
# We run the programme in the command line with this command: 

#      scrapy crawl jobs -o urls.csv -t csv --logfile log.txt


# We get two output files
#  1) urls.csv
#  2) log.txt

# Url whitelist.
with open("Q:/Big_Data/Spletne_strani_podjetij/strganje/kljucne_besede/url_whitelist.txt", "r+") as kw:
    url_whitelist = kw.read().replace('\n', '').split(",")
url_whitelist = map(str.strip, url_whitelist)

# Tab whitelist.
# We need to replace character the same way as in detector.
with open("Q:/Big_Data/Spletne_strani_podjetij/strganje/kljucne_besede/tab_whitelist.txt", "r+") as kw:
    tab_whitelist = kw.read().decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode('utf-8')
tab_whitelist = tab_whitelist.replace('Ŕ', 'č')
tab_whitelist = tab_whitelist.replace('L', 'č')
tab_whitelist = tab_whitelist.replace('Ő', 'š')
tab_whitelist = tab_whitelist.replace('Ü', 'š')
tab_whitelist = tab_whitelist.replace('Ä', 'ž')
tab_whitelist = tab_whitelist.replace('×', 'ž')
tab_whitelist = tab_whitelist.replace('\n', '').split(",")
tab_whitelist = map(str.strip, tab_whitelist)



# Look for occupations in url.
with open("Q:/Big_Data/Spletne_strani_podjetij/strganje/kljucne_besede/occupations_url.txt", "r+") as occ_url:
    occupations_url = occ_url.read().replace('\n', '').split(",")
occupations_url = map(str.strip, occupations_url)

# Look for occupations in tab.
# We need to replace character the same way as in detector.
with open("Q:/Big_Data/Spletne_strani_podjetij/strganje/kljucne_besede/occupations_tab.txt", "r+") as occ_tab:
    occupations_tab = occ_tab.read().decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode('utf-8')
occupations_tab = occupations_tab.replace('Ŕ', 'č')
occupations_tab = occupations_tab.replace('L', 'č')
occupations_tab = occupations_tab.replace('Ő', 'š')
occupations_tab = occupations_tab.replace('Ü', 'š')
occupations_tab = occupations_tab.replace('Ä', 'ž')
occupations_tab = occupations_tab.replace('×', 'ž')
occupations_tab = occupations_tab.replace('\n', '').split(",")
occupations_tab = map(str.strip, occupations_tab)

#Join url whitelist and occupations.
url_whitelist_occupations = url_whitelist + occupations_url

#Join tab whitelist and occupations.
tab_whitelist_occupations = tab_whitelist + occupations_tab


#base = open("G:/myVE/vacancies/bazni.txt", "w")
#non_base = open("G:/myVE/vacancies/ne_bazni.txt", "w")


class JobSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    #Name of spider
    name = "jobs"

    #start_urls = open("Q:\Big_Data\Utrip\spletne_strani.txt", "r+").readlines()[0]
    #print urls
    #start_urls = map(str.strip, urls)
    #Start urls
    start_urls = ["http://www.alius.si"]
    print "\nSpletna stran         ", start_urls, "\n"

    #Result of the programme is this list of job vacancies webpages.
    jobs_urls = []


    def parse(self, response):

        #Theoretically I could save the HTML of webpage to be able to check later and see how it looked like
        # at the time of downloading. That is important for validation, because it is easier to look at nice HTML webpage instead of naked text.
        # but I have to write a pipeline http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/item-pipeline.html

        response.selector.remove_namespaces()
        #print "response url" , str(response.url)

        #Take url of response, because we would like to stay on the same domain.
        parsed = urlparse(response.url)

        #Base url.        
        #base_url = get_base_url(response).strip()
        base_url = parsed.scheme+'://'+parsed.netloc
        #print "base url" , str(base_url)
        #If the urls grows from seeds, it's ok, otherwise not.
        if base_url in self.start_urls:
            #print "base url je v start"
            #base.write(response.url+"\n")



            #net1 = parsed.netloc

            #Take all urls, they are marked by "href" or "data-link". These are either webpages on our website either new websites.
            urls_href = response.xpath('//@href').extract()    
            urls_datalink = response.xpath('//@data-link').extract()
            urls = urls_href + urls_datalink
            #print "povezave na tej strani ", urls




            #Loop through all urls on the webpage.
            for url in urls:

                #Test all new urls. NE DELA

                #print "url ", str(url)

                #If url doesn't start with "http", it is relative url, and we add base url to get absolute url.       
                if not (url.startswith("http")):

                    #Povežem delni url z baznim url.
                    url = urljoin(base_url,url).strip()

                #print "new url ", str(url)

                new_parsed = urlparse(url)
                new_base_url = new_parsed.scheme+'://'+new_parsed.netloc
                #print "new base url ", str(new_base_url)

                if new_base_url in self.start_urls:
                    #print "yes"

                    url = url.replace("\r", "")
                    url = url.replace("\n", "")
                    url = url.replace("\t", "")
                    url = url.strip()

                    #Remove anchors '#', that point to a section on the same webpage, because this is the same webpage.
                    #But we keep question marks '?', which mean, that different content is pulled from database.
                    if '#' in url:
                        index = url.find('#')   
                        url = url[:index]
                        if url in self.jobs_urls:
                            continue




                    #Ignore ftp and sftp.
                    if url.startswith("ftp") or url.startswith("sftp"):

                        continue





                    #Compare each url on the webpage with original url, so that spider doesn't wander away on the net.
                    #net2 = urlparse(url).netloc
                    #test.write("lokacija novega url "+ str(net2)+"\n")

                    #if net2 != net1:
                    #    continue
                        #test.write("ni ista lokacija, nadaljujemo\n")

                    #If the last character is slash /, I remove it to avoid duplicates.
                    if url[len(url)-1] == '/':           
                        url = url[:(len(url)-1)]


                    #If url includes characters like %, ~ ... it is LIKELY NOT to be the one I are looking for and I ignore it. 
                    #However in this case I exclude good urls like http://www.mdm.si/company#employment
                    if any(x in url for x in ['%', '~',

                        #slike
                        '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.eps', '.ico', '.svg', '.tif', '.tiff',
                        '.JPG', '.JPEG', '.PNG', '.GIF', '.EPS', '.ICO', '.SVG', '.TIF', '.TIFF',

                        #dokumenti
                        '.xls', '.ppt', '.doc', '.xlsx', '.pptx', '.docx', '.txt', '.csv', '.pdf', '.pd', 
                        '.XLS', '.PPT', '.DOC', '.XLSX', '.PPTX', '.DOCX', '.TXT', '.CSV', '.PDF', '.PD', 

                        #glasba in video
                        '.mp3', '.mp4', '.mpg', '.ai', '.avi', '.swf',
                        '.MP3', '.MP4', '.MPG', '.AI', '.AVI', '.SWF',

                        #stiskanje in drugo
                        '.zip', '.rar', '.css', '.flv', '.xml'
                        '.ZIP', '.RAR', '.CSS', '.FLV', '.XML'

                        #Twitter, Facebook, Youtube
                        '://twitter.com', '://mobile.twitter.com', 'www.twitter.com', 
                        'www.facebook.com', 'www.youtube.com'

                        #Feeds, RSS, arhiv
                        '/feed', '=feed', '&feed', 'rss.xml', 'arhiv'


                                ]):

                        continue


                    #We need to save original url for xpath, in case we change it later (join it with base_url)
                    #url_xpath = url                    


                    #We don't want to go to other websites. We want to stay on our website, so we keep only urls with domain (netloc) of the company we are investigating.         
                    #if (urlparse(url).netloc == urlparse(base_url).netloc):



                    #The main part. We look for webpages, whose urls include one of the employment words as strings.
                    #We will check the tab of the url as well. This is additional filter, suggested by Dan Wu, to improve accuracy. 
                    #tabs = response.xpath('//a[@href="%s"]/text()' % url_xpath).extract()
                    tabs = response.xpath('//a[@href="%s"]/text()' % url).extract()

                    # Sometimes tabs can be just empty spaces like '\t' and '\n' so in this case we replace it with [].
                    # That was the case when the spider didn't find this employment url: http://www.terme-krka.com/si/sl/o-termah-krka/o-podjetju-in-skupini-krka/zaposlitev/
                    tabs = [tab.encode('utf-8') for tab in tabs]
                    tabs = [tab.replace('\t', '') for tab in tabs]
                    tabs = [tab.replace('\n', '') for tab in tabs]
                    tab_empty = True
                    for tab in tabs:
                        if tab != '':
                            tab_empty = False
                    if tab_empty == True:
                        tabs = []


                    # -- Instruction. 
                    # -- Users in other languages, please insert employment words in your own language, like jobs, vacancies, career, employment ... --
                    # Starting keyword_url is zero, then we add keywords as we find them in url. 
                    keyword_url = ''
                    #for keyword in url_whitelist:
                    for keyword in url_whitelist_occupations:

                        if keyword in url:
                            keyword_url = keyword_url + keyword + ' '
                    # a) If we find at least one keyword in url, we continue.
                    if keyword_url != '':                

                        #1. Tabs are empty.
                        if tabs == []:



                            #We found url that includes one of the magic words and also the text includes a magic word. 
                            #We check url, if we have found it before. If it is new, we add it to the list "jobs_urls".
                            if url not in self.jobs_urls :


                                self.jobs_urls.append(url)
                                item = JobItem()
                                item["url"] = url
                                #item["keyword_url"] = keyword_url
                                #item["keyword_url_tab"] = ' '
                                #item["keyword_tab"] = ' '
                                print "Zaposlitvena podstran ", url

                                #We return the item.
                                yield item



                        #2. There are texts in tabs, one or more.
                        else:

                            #For the same partial url several texts are possible.
                            for tab in tabs:                            

                                #We search for keywords in tabs.
                                keyword_url_tab = ''
                                #for key in tab_whitelist:
                                for key in tab_whitelist_occupations:

                                    if key in tab:
                                        keyword_url_tab = keyword_url_tab + key + ' '

                                # If we find some keywords in tabs, then we have found keywords in both url and tab and we can save the url.
                                if keyword_url_tab != '':

                                    # keyword_url_tab starts with keyword_url from before, because we want to remember keywords from both url and tab. So we add initial keyword_url.
                                    keyword_url_tab = 'URL ' + keyword_url + ' TAB ' + keyword_url_tab

                                    #We found url that includes one of the magic words and also the tab includes a magic word. 
                                    #We check url, if we have found it before. If it is new, we add it to the list "jobs_urls".
                                    if url not in self.jobs_urls:                             

                                        self.jobs_urls.append(url)
                                        item = JobItem()
                                        item["url"] = url
                                        #item["keyword_url"] = ' '
                                        #item["keyword_url_tab"] = keyword_url_tab
                                        #item["keyword_tab"] = ' '
                                        print "Zaposlitvena podstran ", url

                                        #We return the item.
                                        yield item

                                #We haven't found any keywords in tabs, but url is still good, because it contains some keywords, so we save it.
                                else:

                                    if url not in self.jobs_urls:                             

                                        self.jobs_urls.append(url)
                                        item = JobItem()
                                        item["url"] = url
                                        #item["keyword_url"] = keyword_url
                                        #item["keyword_url_tab"] = ' '
                                        #item["keyword_tab"] = ' '
                                        print "Zaposlitvena podstran ", url

                                        #We return the item.
                                        yield item                            

                    # b) If keyword_url = empty, there are no keywords in url, but perhaps there are keywords in tabs. So we check tabs.
                    else:
                        for tab in tabs:


                            keyword_tab = ''
                            #for key in tab_whitelist:
                            for key in tab_whitelist_occupations:


                                if key in tab:
                                    keyword_tab = keyword_tab + key + ' '
                            if keyword_tab != '':                           

                                if url not in self.jobs_urls:                             

                                    self.jobs_urls.append(url)
                                    item = JobItem()
                                    item["url"] = url
                                    #item["keyword_url"] = ' '
                                    #item["keyword_url_tab"] = ' '
                                    #item["keyword_tab"] = keyword_tab
                                    print "Zaposlitvena podstran ", url

                                    #We return the item.
                                    yield item                  

                    #We don't put "else" sentence because we want to further explore the employment webpage to find possible new employment webpages.
                    #We keep looking for employment webpages, until we reach the DEPTH set in settings.py. 
                    yield Request(url, callback = self.parse)

            #else:
                #non_base.write(response.url+"\n")
```

Comment: how would it be different to stop the complete spider on a specific "time" than stopping it per domain?

Comment: @eLRuLL The difference is that the spider crawls ten websites and if I stop it after 200 seconds I cannot be sure that each website got 20 seconds. It might be that one website consumes all the time and others are left behind. And I don't know about processes and how requests are processed inside the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `scrapyd` to schedule 2000 single web-site crawls. Set `max_proc` = 10 [[1](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#max-proc)] to run 10 spiders in parallel. Set spider's `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT` [[2](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-timeout)] to 20 run every spider for 20 seconds. Stop using Windows natively because it's a pain. I've observed Scrapy and scrapyd run faster inside in a VM rather than natively on Windows. I might be wrong - so try for yourself to cross-check but I have a strong feeling that if you use an [Ubuntu 14.04 virtualbox image](http://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-images-for-virtualbox-vmware/) on Windows, it will be faster. Your crawl will take exactly 2000 * 20 / 10 = 17 minutes.

Comment: Thank you @neverlastn , that looks good. If I will manage to manage it, because I am not so technologically advanced. I am just developing some application at work and I don't really like it. Just it would be good if it runs faster. This is the project that I started and now somehow I am bearing it.

Comment: @Marko - glad! Try it for some time and if it doesn't work let me know. I'm quite certain this solution works :)

Comment: Yes well I work at national statistical office and we are linked to faculty of computer science, that is helping us with machine learning tool Orange, that is build on Python. So since they are Python programmers, I might ask them for help :)